# Enlarge IP Network Address Space

Tags: networking, routing, ip

Our small company uses a 192.68.0.0/24 network. As there are only 256 IP addresses, we will be running out of IP addresses soon. I wonder about the best strategy to change the network. Some devices get their IP addresses via DHCP, some devices have fixed IP addresses. There is a DNS server.

I had a look at these questions: [IP Address Planning for our Network](https://serverfault.com/questions/408787/ip-address-planning-for-our-network) and [Hazards of increasing network size by changing the netmask](https://serverfault.com/questions/286144/hazards-of-increasing-network-size-by-changing-the-netmask).
There was a lot of useful information.

Would you advise to change the network to a 192.168.0.0/16 network, requiring us to change the netmask of every device, but allowing us to keep the old addresses? Or should we go for a new network such as 10.0.0.0/16? Or should we have two separate networks (192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24) and a router?

Are there any caveats you would advise us to pay close attention to?

Comment: Change your subnet mask to /23. That doubles the usable ip address space.

Answer (score 0):

You better start adding another subnet as you suggest two separate network and a router because the Broadcast domain with more the 200 users are considered unstable and poor performance. You cant manage a /16 on same broadcast network

Comment: `the Broadcast domain with more the 200 users are considered unstable and poor performance` - Can you cite your sources for that information or is that your opinion?

Comment: Depends on the devices that are used, if you use  cheap unmanageable switchs and you let all your 500 devices on a broadcast domain I think that should be problems. If you use cisco you may use 500-1000 as they suggest but personally this is my opinion no more than 250 active users

Comment: I have 1 year dealing with this problem here :/ http://serverfault.com/questions/691955/domain-pc-freezes-the-nic-blocks-all-l3-connectivity-on-that-switch

Comment: OK, but you know that that's unrelated to the broadcast domain, right? That problem looks like a faulty NIC and it looks like it's being exacerbated by an unmanaged switch. If you fix or replace the faulty NIC that will probably solve the problem. If you replace the switch with a managed switch that should prevent future occurrences of the problem from affecting the entire network.

Comment: that's the problem, it is not a NIC is a randomly PC on domain. every 2 month a different PC freeze. For some reason or another a device will fail and all domain on same L2 will go down if this happen and if the switch can't isolate the problem, anyway this is still personal opinion :)